# Email only receive in gmail mail id's .Cannot deliver in others

Tags: php, html, .net, ajax, codeigniter

```
    $to_email = "suraj@gmail.com,rajeesh@paarva.com,arun@paarva.com,arunrmt@gmail.com";
    $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
    $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $msg = $this->input->post('msg');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");


    $config = Array(        
        'protocol' => 'sendmail',
       'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from($from_email, $fname);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject('Contact enquiry' . ' ' . $fname . ' ' . $mobile);

    $email_body = "<table style='width:700px;border:1px #e5e5e5 solid;background:#f5f5f5;color:#000000;padding:7px;'><tbody><tr><td style='width:120px;padding-left:3px;border:1px #FFFFFF solid;background:#f15722;color:#FFF;'><strong>Name:</strong></td><td style='border:1px #e5e5e5 solid; padding:5px;background:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;'>" . $fname . "." . $lname . "</td></tr><tr><td style='width:120px;padding-left:3px;border:1px #FFFFFF solid;background:#f15722;color:#FFF;'><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td style='border:1px #e5e5e5 solid; padding:5px;background:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;'>".$mobile."</td></tr><tr><td style='width:120px;padding-left:3px;border:1px #FFFFFF solid;background:#f15722;color:#FFF;'><strong>Email Id:</strong></td><td style='border:1px #e5e5e5 solid; padding:5px;background:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;'>".$email."</td></tr><tr><td style='width:120px;padding-left:3px;border:1px #FFFFFF solid;background:#f15722;color:#FFF;'><strong>Message:</strong></td><td style='border:1px #e5e5e5 solid;padding:7px;background:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;line-height:19px;'>".$msg."</td></tr></tbody></table>"; 
    $body = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", "$email_body");
    $this->email->message($email_body);


    if ($this->email->send()) {
        //echo $body;
        echo 'Email sent successfully'; 
    } else {
        echo 'Error in sending Email';
    }
}
```

> email are send to gmail id s only eg:suraj@gmail.com,arunmt@gmail.com. And mail not receive in email id like rajeesh@paarva.com,ajeeb@paarva.com . please help me

Comment: Also give `mailpath` in the config array and try.

Comment: how to confiq mauilpath

Comment: Why you are using protocol as `sendmail`?

Comment: i am using this protocol.. is thereb any prob with that

Comment: you can use the default one `mail`. Try this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences-in-a-config-file)

Comment: no i tried with both mail,smtp,send mail ...my mails are delivering to gmail mails.... not suraj@paarva.com etc

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            $this->email->initialize(array(
              'protocol' => protocol,
              'smtp_host' => host,
              'smtp_user' => user,
              'smtp_pass' => password,
              'smtp_port' => smtp port,
              'crlf' => "\r\n",
              'newline' => "\r\n"
            ));

            $this->email->email, 'eJobs');
            $this->email->to(email);
            $this->email->subject('subject');
            $this->email->message("you're message");
            $this->email->send();
```